# Help with expressing Partition Numbers as powers of two

Tags: exponential-function, functional-equations

Grateful for some help with expressing Partition Numbers as powers of two.  I'm not great at maths, but this is as far as I have got: 
$P(n)=n/2+2^{n-1}-(2^{n-2})(2^x)$ where $x$ is an exponential that approaches $1$.
Please note that I have amended the equation and added $n/2$ to avoid trying to find exponentials which give a value of zero which is not possible.  This has also affected the values for $x$.

[image]
Does anyone know the equation to calculate $x$ as this would be a neat way of calculating the Partition.

Many thanks
Mark Millett